# Send struct pointers to WndProc for multiple dialog instances

Tags: c, winapi, pointers, struct

I'm stuck. I have a vector of structs, one of its members is `HWND`. I use these HWNDs to process messages, and the other members are for instance-specific parameters. I pass a pointer to each newly created struct instance to the WndProc using `lpParam`. Sounds about right.

Inside the Proc I'm trying to get the passed pointer and tie all the instance-specific variables to the struct pointed by it. It seems the standard way for that is this:

```
HexParams Hex;
if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
    SetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) ((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    return TRUE;
} else {
    LONG_PTR lpUserData = GetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, GWLP_USERDATA);
    Hex = *(HexParams *)lpUserData;
}
switch (uMsg) {
case WM_CREATE: {
    // use "Hex.Member"
```

It happens so that I'm sizing the dialog in a certain way, and I'm handling `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` for that. And inside it, I already use a `Hex` struct member called `Running`.

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO: {
    MINMAXINFO *pInfo = (MINMAXINFO *) lParam;
    // Manual adjust to account for cell parameters
    pInfo->ptMinTrackSize.y = Hex.CellHeight * 2 + ClientTopGap;
    if (Hex.Running) {
        pInfo->ptMinTrackSize.x = TextArea.left + ClientXGap;
        pInfo->ptMaxTrackSize.x = TextArea.right + ClientXGap;
    }
    return 0;
    break;
}
```

Which is then used in `WM_CREATE` too, to figure out how to size it and when.

I'm in a vicious circle: I can't get the proper struct pointer out of `lpParam` until `WM_NCCREATE` arrives, but it's not the first message to arrive! And in the one that in fact arrives first I already need the scruct. And in that first message it's not possible to get it!

Comment: To break the *vicious circle* you need to subclass your window instances prior to any messages being sent to them. One way to go about it is to set up a [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) for the calling thread and perform the custom data initialization in a `HCBT_CREATEWND` handler. For a demonstration you can check out the MFC implementation of `_AfxCbtFilterHook` (wincore.cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore those early messages, returning `DefWindowProc()` values for those. Those aren't going to be the important ones; you'll get more messages later down the line. (Remember that `GWLP_USERDATA` is initially zero.)

See also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/03/10496248.aspx) (note the date this was posted). (Yes, this annoyed me at first, but I'm not fond of a window hook-based solution, and in practice it works fine, and if Raymond Chen does it...)

Comment: How can I ignore them if I need them explicitly?

Comment: Remember that `GWLP_USERDATA` is initially zero. If your structure pointer is `NULL`, don't bother doing any of your window procedure. (See the second link.) If it turns out you actually needed those very first messages, let me know.

Comment: Used your approach, seems to work. But there is another problem now. It's impossible to write to vector's element members by using `Hex.Member = stuff`. It only works when done `Hex->Member = stuff`. But all my code is written as the former. Is there a solution, or I should create a new question?

Comment: You should be using a pointer to `HexParams` throughout your program's execution (this means having to dynamically allocate `Hex` if it's a local variable); it'll make things easier and less buggy. Just store the address to your `HexParams` into the `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm allocating an instance of HexParams struct before calling CreateWindowEx, and passing there a pointer to that struct. But as you can see in my code, I'm trying to work with it by `.`, not by `->`, and fail. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Other than change every instance of `.` to `->`, you can say `(*p).xxx` instead. Just use `->`; it's neater. `->` is the same as `.`, but it does the pointer indirection for you.